# ng2-bootstrap dropdowns not working with angular-2-beta and bootstrap4

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, ng2-bootstrap

I am using the [angular2 5 min quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html).

When I try to use the bare-minimum markups and Component provided at [ng2-bootstrap drowdowns directive](http://valor-software.github.io/ng2-bootstrap/index-bs4.html#dropdowns), I encouter 3 issues

1. The Caret doesn't appear
2. The dropdowns don't work
3. Split-button caret appears but half the size of primary action
   button.

Here are my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
   "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
   "bootstrap": "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tarball/v4-dev",
   "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
   "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
   "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.1-beta.1",
   "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
   "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
   "systemjs": "0.19.6",
   "zone.js": "0.5.10"
 },
```

Comment: ng2-boostrap version and angular2 version I am using are conflicting.
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/97

Comment: Have you considered PrimeNG dropdown? http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown